# When should I convert a Lead into Potential or Contacts in ZohoCRM?

Tags: crm, zoho

Recently I've started using ZohoCRM and I have a question about the sales process. What's the differente between converting a Lead into a Contact or Potential, I mean, as I say a Contact is the person who your company make business, then, it's a potential too.

So, I wanna know when to set as a Contact or Potential, and if there is some "default" order to consider.

Obs: if my question is posted on wrong site within StackExchange please sign me which site I have to post it.

Thanks for help.

Answer (score -2):

This is the way my workplace does it:

Potentials are people who have inquired about services.  We then have Accounts which are registered to a company.  Contacts are a subsection of the Accounts.  Potentials are people who have already opened an account, have received a quote, and are looking to finalize a purchase.

Comment: While this can naybe answer the question. The question is per si off-topic